# Wordpress Server to localhost Not Found The requested URL /xxx/ was not found on this server

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using **wamp server** with  php admin . How can I move live WordPress server file as my localhost? Even I configured local host, changed the site URL and home URL in my database and changed permalink,  it just enters into my home page and my WP-admin panel as local host, while enter into my home page while clicking my nave links it show me 404 not found URL. how can I outcome this problem?

Comment: check your .htaccess file for path

Answer (score 0):

@Dev is probably right! (unless you didnt changed your DB)...

1. try renaming you existing .htaccess or temporarily moving it (better)
2. let wordpress create a new one by resetting the permalink and redefining them.

Lets us know if this helps

Comment: I had moved out my .htaccess file from wordpress,And i cant reset or redefile the permalink . and in my db file i have wp-posts field. in that filed all the contents are redirecting to the server host. am i need to change all the post content to localhost/myfile.

Comment: Dont do anything fast ;)  -  take a moment to learn how to transffer a website to localhost on Youtube... There are plenty tutorials on this subject.. before you upload your transffered db to your >> local phpMyAdmin you should ofcourse change the urls so they fit the current installation address... If you havent done so i am guessing this is your first time? Please take a moment to view a tutorial (it would save a lot of time) ;)